# Faulting application name: xyz.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x560a7dee Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll,

Tags: .net

I am getting this error when I run my service and unfortunately I don't know how to handle this error.

error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Suggestions and any kind of help is highly appreciated.

the error which is showing in event viewer is as below.

> Faulting application name: xyz.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp:
>   0x560a7dee Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   6.3.9600.17055, time stamp: 0x532943a3 Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x00011d4d Faulting process id: 0x710 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01d0faaf6c287c06 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\XYZ.exe Faulting module path:
>   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   aa9f9e79-66a2-11e5-80cc-005056aa451c Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This is very important for you to know :)

Comment: Your program crashed with an unhandled .NET exception.  So sure, it isn't very likely to respond to a start request in a timely fashion, it is a dead parrot :)  Every .NET programmer eventually discovers that writing an event handler for the AppDomain.Current.UnhandledException event is not optional.